# How to extract the envelope from a sound file?

Tags: audio, signal-processing, nyquist

I need to extract the [sound wave envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_detector) from a set of audio files in a batch job on a headless Linux host.

I think this can be achieved using the [Nyquist programming language](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/nyquist.html), a variant of Lisp notably embedded in audacity, and dedicated to sound processing. However, if I have some familiarities with Lisp, I don't have any previous experience with Nyquist.

Is there some primitive in Nyquist to achieve that directly? Or how can I write a short Nyquist program to extract the envelope of a sound?

---

I tried using the [snd-avg](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rbd/doc/nyquist/part8.html#index693) function. But it does not seem to produce a smooth envelope (upper half in the screenshot):

```
(snd-avg
  (aref *track* 0)                 ; first sound
  (truncate (/ *sound-srate* 50))  ; 50 Hz to samples
  1 op-peak)                       ; follow peak values
```

[image: Envelope obtained using <code>snd-avg</code>]

Comment: Maybe have a look over here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/envelope-extraction-using-the-analytic-signal.html  I have no idea how you would do it in your language, but using the Hilbert transform (or a pair of Hilbert-transform-related filters) is the first thing I would try.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Matt, that was a very useful reading!

Answer (score 0):

I obtained decently good results by applying a low-pass filter after `snd-avg` in order to remove the staircase ripples:

```
(lp 
  (snd-avg
    (aref *track* 0)
    (truncate (/ *sound-srate* 1000)) ; 1kHz
    1 op-peak)
  50)                                 ; 50 Hz low-pass
```

[image]